# Only show a Post once in 10 visits

Tags: posts, javascript

I would like to show certain Wordpress Post to one in 10 people. I am guessing it would be a JS solution which simply hides to post using a random number generator.

Has anyone ever face a similar scenario and care to show how they solved it?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate how do you wish to show the post to the 10th visitor? in sidebar? popup? or??

Comment: Sorry, within the loop itself

Comment: And please can you specify which kind of post you want to show? some random post or??? The answer highly depends on what you want to show to visitors.

Comment: Specific Posts (Array of Post ID's)

Comment: I didn't quite understand how you want to do it, but this should be done using php. You can use `rand(1,10);` to generate a random number, and then show your post. If you make a clear example of what you want, i can write a specific code for you.

Comment: So let's say I have 2 posts that I only want to display 1 in 10 times. Post ID 100 & Post ID 101. These post are inside my standard loop.

Comment: Would it be as simple as $i = rand(10,100); then if($i = 10) {show post}

Answer (score 2):

```
        function lsmwp_post_limter($ids, $in, $count) {
          $i = rand(1,$count);
          if ($i <= $in) {
            return($ids);
          }
          else
            return false;
        }

        function lsmWpfilter($posts){
            $result = [];
            foreach($posts as $post){
                $res = lsmwp_post_limter($post['postId'], $post['in'], $post['count']);
                if ($res){

                    $result[] = $res;
                }
            }
            print_r($result);
            return $result;
        }

        $exluded_posts = array(
            array('postId' => 28741 , 'in' => 2, 'count' => 3),
            array('postId' => 29811 , 'in' => 2, 'count' => 3),
            array('postId' => 31951     , 'in' => 1, 'count' => 3)
        );


        $custom_args = array(
            'post__not_in' => lsmWpfilter($exluded_posts),
        );
```

This method allows me to use different in/count for each excluded posts, not limiting it to 1/5 and also making use of funcitons

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have specific post IDs that you want to show randomly (1 per 10), you can use:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
      if($post->ID==100 OR $post->ID==101){
            if (rand(1,10)==5) {the_content();}
      else
            the_content();}
endwhile;
```

Note that this code doesn't count the visitors and display the post each time a 10th visitor accesses the page. For that, you will need to create a variable and store the counter value inside the database. However this will serve almost like the way you wanted.

Comment: I used your rand suggestion and took it a bit further